# Planar graph K3,3

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I need a little help with graphs in the field of graph theory.

I have 3 undirected graphs :
A1 = {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}, {{x1, x2}, {x1, x3}, {x1, x8}, {x2, x6}, {x2, x7 }, {x3, x4}, {x3, x5}, {x3, x8}, {x4, x7}, {x5, x6}, {x5, x7}, {x5, x8}, {x6, x7}, {x6, x8}}}

A2 = {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}, {{x1, x2}, {x1, x7}, {x2, x3}, {x2, x6}, {x2, x8 }, {x3, x4}, {x3, x8}, {x4, x5}, {x4, x7}, {x5, x6}, {x5, x7}, {x5, x8}, {x6, x7}, {x6, x8}}}

A3 = {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}, {{x1, x2}, {x1, x5}, {x1, x8}, {x2, x3}, {x2, x7 }, {x3, x4}, {x3, x5}, {x3, x6}, {x4, x5}, {x4, x7}, {x4, x8}, {x5, x7}, {x6, x8}, {x7, x8}}}

The situation is as follows: I examined the isomorphism and planarity of the graphs and I got the following results: A1 is isomorphic to A2, A1 is not isomorphic to A3, A2 is not isomorphic to A3. I managed to draw A1 and A2 it can be drawn in such a way that no edges cross each other. Which means that A1 and A2 are planar but A3 is not. I also tested all this using python algorithms and the networkx library. But graph A3 is not planar and I know it is not, but trying to make K3,3 I can't do it at all, does anyone have an idea from you how I could do it?

[image: This is graph A3]
This is A3

Comment: "I managed to draw $A_1$ and$A_2$ it can be drawn in such a way that no edges cross each other. Which means that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are planar but $A_3$ is not." The logic doesn't make sense here. Just because $A_1$ and $A_2$ are planar doesn't mean that $A_3$ is not.

Comment: As for your main question: keep in mind that Kuratowksi's Theorem says that a nonplanar graph must have a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. Have you looked for both?

Comment: It turns out that it does contain both. @kabenyuk has given $K_{3,3}$; for $K_5$, delete vertices $x_1,x_2,x_6$, and add the edges $x_3x_6,x_3x_7,x_5x_8$.

Comment: @Théophile yes but , but I think I immediately realized that A1 and A2 are planned, and I have to continue to check A3 with the help of other methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the graph $A_3$ remove vertex $x_6$ but add edge $x_3x_8$.
Remove vertex $x_4$. The result is $K_{3,3}$. Its parts are $\{1,3,7\}$ and $\{2,5,8\}$.